# Statistical properties of parameters estimated by method of Lagrange multipliers in R

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, mathematical-statistics

I have time series data that can be fitted by a constrained non-linear function (non-linear in the parameters to be estimated).  I'd like to use the method of Lagrange Multipliers ([link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)), specifically R's `Rsolnp` package ([link](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rsolnp/Rsolnp.pdf)), because the Lagrange Multiplier itself has economic meaning.  I would like the statistical properties (p values or confidence intervals) of the parameters estimated by `solnp` in `Rsolnp`.

If my problem didn't involve constraints, I could use R's `nls` class ([link](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/nls.html)) and the `summary.nls` method ([link](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/summary.nls.html)) to retrieve the statistical properties of the fitted parameters.

Questions:

- Is there an equivalent to `summary.nls` for `solnp`?
- If not, how can I obtain the statistical properties of the parameters estimated by the method of Lagrange Multipliers? A reference to a paper or textbook here will be sufficient.

Here are some details of my function (a CES production function from economics) and constraints:

Function:

```
iGDP ~ ((1-zeta) * (exp(lambda_L*iYear) * iCapStk^(alpha) * iLabor^beta)^phi + zeta*(exp(lambda_E*iYear) * iQ)^phi)^(1/phi)
```

Constraints:

```
alpha + beta = 1
```

(Note that I don't want to substitute 1-beta for alpha, because the numerical value of the Lagrange Multiplier has a valuable economic interpretation. I want to use the both the constraint equation and the method of Lagrange Multipliers.)

Known data (on an annual basis):

```
iGDP, iYear, iLabor, iCapStk, iQ
```

Parameters to be estimated (these are the parameters for which I would like statistical properties: p values, confidence intervals, etc.):

```
zeta, lambda_E, lambda_L, alpha, beta, phi
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's much you can do with statistical interpretation of Lagrange multipliers with inequality constraints. Most of non-linear statistical inference (as you may have seen in [Ron Gallant's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471802603) or [Newy and McFadden's Handbook of Econometrics chapter](http://ideas.repec.org/h/eee/ecochp/4-36.html)), is mostly asymptotic. However, for large samples, you will have weird distributions of your Lagrange multipliers if their constraints are active in population (see [Andrews' papers](http://econpapers.repec.org/article/ecmemetrp/v_3a67_3ay_3a1999_3ai_3a6_3ap_3a1341-1384.htm) on estimation on the boundary of the parameter space).

With equality constraints, inference for Lagrange multipliers is doable. At least, I have seen this done for empirical likelihood (see e.g. Theorem 15.2.1 in [Bruce Hansen's Econometrics Notes](http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/econometrics/Econometrics.pdf)).